# Created list with own templateType=10001 but Variation Tab is missing

Tags: list, custom

Created custom list with own templateType=10001 but Variation Tab is missing. I can see for tempatetype=100 or others like task, calender etc. Please help

Comment: Please note i am using VS2015 and SP2013

Answer (score 0):

Variation tab only appears for Generic List, Announcements and Document library.

So, Make sure to have the Type of your List Definition as 100.
Please refer below link for more details

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0729a982-f044-4ca7-9f3f-cc18a4a8f21a/variations-tab-missing-from-list?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Comment: I want to use custom template types because I have 2 list and both are in one feature and If i use type 100 then after deployment columns are mixing with each other.

Comment: if i will the get solution of mixing columns between list then surely i will use the type=100

Comment: Any guidance please?